# Equivalent from postgresql to_char(code,'FM00') in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, formatting

I need help with the equivalent to_char from postgresql to Microsoft SQL Server

```
select to_char(g.code,'FM00') as granularity
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain what this piece of code should do

Comment: When asking such a question, it is helpful to include sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the code should be doing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff 
I have added the full code if it helps,
I was asked for help on a migration a day ago, so I have no knowledge of what it should do and limited access to the database, so I'm just like you in that regard.
So I have no sample data or desired results, sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like:

```
select format(g.code, '00')
```